# How to retrieve localized string in nuxt using strings from a JSON file?

Tags: nuxt-i18n

I have a website with many languages. The menu needs to be populated in some components, so to avoid repetition, I wrote a JSON file, with an array of slugs and names.

```json
[
  {
    "slug": "articles",
    "name": "Articles"
  },
  {
    "slug": "gallery",
    "name": "Gallery"
  },
  {
    ...
  }
]
```

I import the JSON file and, inside the template, populate the menu with:

```js
  <li v-for="link in links" 
  :key="link.name">
  <NuxtLink :to="localePath('/' + 
  link.slug)">{{ link.name }}
  </NuxtLink></li>
```

It works, but as my menus must be tanslated, I need to use **link.name** value to be passed to $t(), so to retrieve its localized value. If I substitute "{{ link.name }}" with "{{ $t('link.name') }}, even if I have localised strings ready to be called, the HTML output is link.name. I really didn't know how can I use a string from my JSON array and pass it to {{ $t() }} function. Any helps is very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Solved with the following:

```js
  <li v-for="link in links" :key="link.name">
    <NuxtLink :to="localePath('/' + link.slug)">
      <span>{{ $t('main.menu.' + link.slug) }}</span>
    </NuxtLink>
  </li>
```

It happens that the $t() function expect a string, so it needs the '', and my translations are organized so that menus names are under the main.menu object:

```js
export const main = {
  title: 'a great title',
  subtitle: 'an awesome subtitle',
  ui: {
    enter: 'entra',
    ...
  },
  menu: {
    bench: 'On the bench',
    articles: 'Articoli',
    info: 'Informazioni',
    gallery: 'Galleria',
    ...
  },
```

Luckily, we can append variable value to a string with a simple "+", without need any special or mysterious function.

Accomplished mission! ;)